# What is pt.lproj?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

In Xcode 4, I'm getting this error:

```
/Developer/Projects/MyApp/Classes/pt.lproj/Localizable.strings:0: error: The file “Localizable.strings” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

"pt" isn't a language I've used in the app.  I do have several languages that utilize xx.lproj folders but "pt" isn't one of them.  Any ideas what is causing this?

EDIT:
I do see a Portuguese Localizable.strings file under the main Localizable.strings.  It is red and I can't delete it.

Comment: If it is red then it means that this file isn't available. Have you tried to create a dummy file with that name and to point Xcode towards it? Then you may be able to delete it. Sounds weird though, I'm not sure if this will eventually solve your problem...

Comment: I'm not sure how to add that since it isn't a single file.  I have added a pt.lproj folder but it is still red in the project.

Comment: If it's listed in your project in red text, then you should be able to select it and delete it using the keyboard, as opposed to from the drop-down menu.

Comment: It doesn't delete via the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Xcode really gets itself into a state then the nuclear option is to right click on your .xcodeproj and select 'Show Package Contents'. Then open the .pbxproj file in there in a text editor such as TextEdit — it's a use readable file with a JSON-like format. Look through there and remove any references to the mysterious pt.lproj. Be sure to back up your .xcodeproj first, as if you leave the .pbxproj in an invalid state then Xcode will simply refuse to reopen the project.

Comment: I was able to cleanly delete that line from the pbxproj file but it created or revealed a number of other errors.  Not sure if they are related.  These errors surround variables not having definitions and lots of expected specifier-qualifier-list before...  This is an old project.  I opened in Xcode4 and allowed it to modernize the project.  Not sure if I blew something up somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> The file “Localizable.strings” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

I met this issue just now and finally solved it by:

1. Remove References of `Localizable.strings` from your project (**NOT Delete**);
2. Add `Localizable.strings` to "Supporting Files" again by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. (`Localizable.strings` files can be find in `<country_code>.lproj`, they'll be combined automatically).

P.S. It not answers OP's question directly, but it might be help for someone else meet this error. :)